# Why does this VC++ program not compile?

Tags: visual-c++

This came up in a class recently.  The problem is the first occurrence of "ptr" in the if.  The error is "expression must be a modifiable value".

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int * ptr = nullptr;
    int i = 7;
    if (ptr == nullptr && ptr = &i) 
        cout << *ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses are your friend.  The C/C++ operator precedence table is deep and some aspects are not intuitive.

In this case, logical AND (&&) binds tighter than assignment (=). ("Binds tighter" == "is of higher precedence".)

When in doubt, I always use a quick google search for "c operator precedence table" to get a bunch of result pages all of which provide a helpful table in order of precedence.  (Actually, when in doubt *in my own code* I always just add the parentheses in the first place.)